# Discord.js v12 Bot Say Command in different channel (via args?)

Tags: if-statement, arguments, discord, discord.js

Im looking for some help/direction/suggestion... I have my discord bot say command here, its taken me a while to get it this far and working. What im looking for is to adapt the current code  so that i can check if the word after ".say" is a "#channel" and if so send the message there. ie ".say #feedback your welcome" ....... would result in the bot saying "your welcome" in the feedback channel **ELSE** just send the message within the same channel. I hope i have explained myself properly but this is over my head, iv tried to research as much as possible. thanks in advance for your time

```
        case 'say':
                if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Moderator') && !message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Staff')) return message.channel.send('You dont not have the required permissions').then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
                })
                else if (message.content.startsWith(".say")) {
                    if (message.deletable) {
                        message.delete();
                    }
                    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Nothing to say").then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })

                    })
                    message.channel.send(`${(args.slice(1).join(" "))}`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a channel is mention in the incoming message, you can use [Message.mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) property that returns a [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) object.

[MessageMentions.channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=channels) returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) that are mention in the message.

So to check if at least one channel is mention in the message :

```js
if (message.mentions.channels.size > 0) {
   // There is at least 1 channel mention in the message.
} else {
   // No channel mention in the message.
}
```

To send a message to the first channel mention :

```js
message.mentions.channels.first().send("message");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i was going down totally the wrong avenue to achieve what i wanted. I think in my mind i had thought i wanted something like.... taking args[2] splitting the # off the front and remove the > from channel ID etc...

Comment: You're welcome, making a substring to get the channel ID to fetch the channel in the guild could work, but as you can see there is already much more convenient methods/properties in the module.